# Битая кодировка в формах ОС

Tags: php, laravel

При отправке форм с сайта в теле письма все кирилические и спец символы приходят в виде `%2525D0%2525A2%2525D0%2525B5%2525D1%252581%2525D1%252582` - текст в форме был "тест"

Шаблон страницы/формы,шаблон письма сохранены в кодировке UTF-8, в шаблоне страницы так же указана кодировка UTF-8 в head страницы

Answer (score 0):

Стоит убедиться, что форма отправляется методом POST.

Если форма специфическая, как вариант использовать `urldecode($text)`